# How to replace only not sent null fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

How to replace only not sent null fields.

**My Product Instance:**

```
Product p1 = new Product(){ Name : "Apple", Money: 2 };
```

**My Document:**

```
{  
   "Id" : 1
   "Name" : "Apppple",
   "Money" : 3,
   "Color" : "Red"
}
```

**I runned this code:**

```
var _filterDef = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, 1);
ProductCollection.ReplaceOne(_filterDef, p1);
```

**Result: Red named field is null...**

```
{  
   "Id" : 1
   "Name" : "Apple",
   "Money" : 2,
   "Color" : null
}
```

**I Want to Result: Red named field is not null**

```
{  
   "Id" : 1
   "Name" : "Apple",
   "Money" : 2,
   "Color" : "Red"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you send the entire document as a update or you use `UpdateOne` for updating fields selectively.

```
var _filterDef = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, 1);
var update = Builders<Product>.Update.Set("Name", "Apple").Set("Money", 2);
ProductCollection.UpdateOne(_filterDef, update );
```

More examples here https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/update/

Comment: Np. I don't think so when using driver directly. You may find some object modelling frameworks which will removes this interaction and directly map your model into mongo db documents but I don`t have any names.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to update the document rather than replace it. In that case use the update operation documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). You'll need to use the "$set" operator as in the [example in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set).